# iPhone with Outlook 2013

Tags: iphone, ms-office

I recently installed Outlook 2013 on my iPhone 5C. But I cannot find any option how to add a new contact to my list. Secondly, how can I sync my iCloud contacts with my Outlook 2013 installed on iPhone 5C.

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful... Could you include that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the Outlook app on your iPhone
2. Tap "Settings"
3. Tap Add Account
4. From the new screen tap "iCloud"
5. Type in your iCloud account credentials

Outlook will now source all email and contacts from your iCloud account.